# Serve a node_module using Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make a specific node module available to my client in my SPA mean stack application. My app structure is as follows:

-app/

--index.html

-node_modules/

-index.js

and i would like to make the module angular-simple-sidebar available in my front end by doing this in my index.js file:

```
'use strict';
let express = require('express');
let routes = require('./api/routes');
let path = require('path');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.start = Date.now();
  next();
});

// ***** THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE *****
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/angular-simple-sidebar'));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './app')));
app.use(routes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {
    root: ('./app')
  });
});

/* GET Api index page */
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('404 page not found!', 404);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Express server is listening on port 3000');
});

module.exports = app;
```

and then use that path in my index.html file:

```
<head>
<script src="scripts/angular-simple-sidebar.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

However all i get in my chrome console is this:

[image: chrome console output]

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried the same, but it's working for me.

I loaded an external CSS file.

Here is my code

---

index.js

```
// Get the required modules
const express = require('express');


let path = require('path');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const host = 'localhost';

var app = express();


// For serving static assets

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {
    root: (__dirname + '/public')
  });
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, function (){
    console.log(`Server running on http://${host}:${port}`)
});
```

---

public/index.html (In your case this one is app/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

css/style.css

```
h1{
    color: red;
}
```

---

Also, try to remove the 'scripts' part from providing the static files and run.

---

index.js

```
// ***** THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE *****
app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/angular-simple-sidebar'));
```

---

index.html

```
<head>
<script src="angular-simple-sidebar.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

If the above fails to run, then give some more details or share the code through Github.

Answer (score 0):

just add a leading slash

```
<head>
<script src="/scripts/angular-simple-sidebar.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried installing same module and it works fine for me with your code.  I can access those files .. Here is my code

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/angular-simple-sidebar'));
app.get('/' ,(req, res) => {
    res.send("<script src='scripts/angular-simple-sidebar.min.js'/>");
});
```

i think there is some other issue with your routes .. can you provide me the code in app/ folder where the actual `app()` function is running and if in case it is taking more time to resolve this .. you can move the static files from `node_modules` to your `public/` static folder if these are just static content and see if it works